# If my Android Things app has no UI, do I need to use background threads?

Tags: android, android-things

I'm writing an app using Android Things, and most of the [samples](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples) don't use any UI even though they use Activities. Do I still need to use background threads for my Android Things app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, your Android Things app does have UI. Everything you can do with a normal Android app (such as `setContentView()`, working with `View`s and `ViewGroup`s, and so on) you can also do in your Android Things app, and if you use a board connected to a display, you can see this UI on the display. In fact, if the display supports touch such as [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/), you can even interact with the UI like a normal Android app.

Whether or not you use any of the standard UI toolkit, your Application is just like any other and still must adhere to Android’s threading policies, e.g. you cannot perform network operations on the main thread. As with any other app, the operating system still monitors your app’s main thread for responsiveness, so if interaction with your peripherals can perform long running or blocking operations, you should use a background thread to prevent the system thinking your application is not responding.

Answer (score 3):

Android Things uses the input event system of Android Activities to receive input from hardware peripherals. i.e. when a button is pushed on your breadboard the Activity receives this as a key event.

If you do not use background threads, your app may be too busy running your code to be able to interpret and/or receive these input events.

Therefore this is why the operating system will still enforce the standard threading policies and why you should use background threads.

From the docs https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html:

> However, Android Things does not require a display. On devices where a graphical display is not present, activities are still a primary component of your Android Things app. This is because the framework delivers all input events to the foreground activity, which has focus. Your app cannot receive key events or motion events through any other application component, such as a service.